# How to run a specific test with Create React App

Tags: unit-testing, create-react-app

In an app create with CRA v.1 I need to run a specific test file. How do I go about it? There is the `--testPathIgnorePatterns` flag to add to the `npm test` script to ignore a file or path but how do I run a particular test file with CRA from the command line?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have done this by using `--` to pass custom arguments to the npm script.

Documentation on this option can be found here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

So, to run a single test in a create-react-app application, I run the following:

```
npm run test -- -t 'test-name'
```

Where `test-name` is the value used in the describe function in jest -

```
describe('test-name', () => {
  it('does something', () => { ... });
});
```

Answer (score 44):

You can use the name of the file in the command, and it will run only it.

For example:

```
npm test src/App.test.js
```

Comment: Note: I came to this answer by chance as I was having the same issue you are. I'm not sure how reliable it is :)

Comment: Thank you. I tried the solution you offered. Here's what I got. I have two test files within client/src: sample.test.js and sample2.test.js. When I run `npm test sample2.test.js` from client/src Jest actually runs sample.test.js and vice versa.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests) or [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html) has something that works.

Comment: For me worked just the file name and not a path: npm test App.test.js

Comment: as of 2022, this works best!

Answer (score 2):

By running the command as the accepted answer mentioned, it will take it as regex and if you have multiple same files name like `index.test.tsx`, it will execute all.

If you are using `jest`, you can run command below to force it to run only single test file:

`npm test --runTestsByPath "src/pages/parentpath/index.test.tsx"`

Refer to [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--runtestsbypath).